# Component state in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

First of all, I am new in ReactJS. I would like to display markers in my MapComponent. I made this work, but to be honest I think there should be better way to do it...
I get props from my parent component, where they are loaded from JSON. I would like to pass coordinates from each item(from my JSON) into markers in state in my MapComponent. I used react-google-maps solution for google maps. 
Maybe someone could give me some advice what would be the best approach in this case? Thanks a lot for any tips!

```
export class MapComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        markers: []
    }
  }


  getMarkers() {
    if (this.props.data.rows) {
      var markers = this.props.data.rows.map(function(item, i) {
        return {
          position: {
            lat: item.coordinate[0],
            lng: item.coordinate[1]
          },
          item: item
        }
      });
      this.setState({
        markers: markers
      });
    }
  }
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return true;
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.getMarkers();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.map}>
      <GoogleMapLoader
        containerElement={
          <div
            {...this.props}
            style={{
              height: "100%",
            }}
          />
        }
        googleMapElement={
          <GoogleMap
            ref={(map) => console.log(map)}
            defaultZoom={9}
            defaultCenter={{lat: 52.379189, lng: 4.899431}}>
            {this.state.markers.map((marker, index) => {
              return (
                <Marker
                {...marker}
                />
              );
            })}
          </GoogleMap>
        }
      />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can do it more easily just with props

Comment: @webdeb what would you suggest? I would need to loop through my items and then through coordinates in GoogleMap?

Comment: My suggestion is to do it on the fly in a single loop, instead of preparing it before.. and then run another loop, to render them, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are passing your state via props, you can ovoid creating a **component class**, you actually just need a simple **representational component**, it is supported since 0.14 (I guess). This **representational components** are just functions, representing the `render` function. This functions take `props` as param

So you Component will look more clean:

```
const MapComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.map}>
      <GoogleMapLoader
        containerElement={
          <div
            {...props}
            style={{height: "100%"}}
          />
        }
        googleMapElement={
          <GoogleMap
            ref={(map) => console.log(map)}
            defaultZoom={9}
            defaultCenter={{lat: 52.379189, lng: 4.899431}}>
              {props.data.rows.map((item, index) => {
                const position = {
                  lat: item.coordinate[0],
                  lng: item.coordinate[1]
                };

                return (
                  <Marker
                    key={index}
                    position={position}
                    item={item}
                  />
              );
            })}
          </GoogleMap>
        }
      />
    </div>);
}
```

Comment: thank you. This is so much better solution than my idea. thank's again.

Answer (score 0):

First, as @webdeb said , better to send the correct data using props. The use of state cause unnecessary redrawing of a component.
Secondly, if for some reason you will need to handle the props and the state as you describe, `componentDidUpdate` method is not suitable for this purpose, you should replace it with `componentWillReceiveProps`

Something like:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
export class MapComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
          markers: []
     }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getMarkers(this.props);
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        if(this.props.data!==nextProps.data){
            const markers = this.getMarkers(nextProps);
            this.setState({
               markers: markers
            });
        }
    }

    getMarkers(props) {
        let markers = [];
        if (props.data.rows) {
            markers = props.data.rows.map(function(item, i) {
              return {
                 position: {
                   lat: item.coordinate[0],
                   lng: item.coordinate[1]
                 },
                 item: item
              }
           });

        } 
        return markers;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hey @yozi. Thank you. I will probably go with webdeb solution. But very good to know how to handle this case in this way. Thank you for your help.